# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy' when parsing Multipart email message

Tags: python, email, mime, multipart, eml

Python 3.6 email module crashes with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "empty-eml.py", line 9, in <module>
    for part in msg.iter_attachments():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/message.py", line 1055, in iter_attachments
    parts = self.get_payload().copy()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

The crash can be reproduced with this EML file,

```
From: "xxx@xxx.xx" <xxx@xxx.xx>
To: <xx@xxx.xx>
Subject: COURRIER EMIS PAR PACIFICA 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="----=_Part_3181_1274694650.1556805728023"
Date: Thu, 2 May 2019 16:02:08 +0200
```

and this piece of minimal code:

```
from email import policy
from email.parser import Parser
from sys import argv


with open(argv[1]) as eml_file:
    msg = Parser(policy=policy.default).parse(eml_file)

for part in msg.iter_attachments():
    pass
```

I believe it has to do something with the Content-Type being `multipart/mixed` together with the email content being empty, which causes `get_payload` to return `str`. However, I am not sure, if such EML is forbidden by standard (but I have many such samples), it is a bug in the email module, or me using the code wrong.

Comment: I discourage you from using `email` module since it is about to be deprecated from 3.8 and removed from 3.10. Consider using another email module. Source: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0594/#email-legacy-api

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that, however, in the source you posted, there is stated following: `Substitute: email (non-legacy APIs)` which means, as I understand it, the `email` module will still be used, just with non-legacy content. Anyway, I don't like the idea of refactoring my whole email parsing platform, and replacing the basis parsing module, for this single error (I'm not even sure if there is such a robust solution for parsing emails in Python as the `email` module).

Comment: Indeed, the code I posted is using the new `email.message.EmailMessage`, which is, in fact, the replacement for the legacy code, so there is nothing deprecated about the code I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the policy to `strict`:

```
Parser(policy=policy.strict).parse(eml_file)
```

the parser raises `email.errors.StartBoundaryNotFoundDefect`, described in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/email.errors.html#module-email.errors) as:

> `StartBoundaryNotFoundDefect` – The start boundary claimed in the Content-Type header was never found.

If you parse the message with `policy.default` and inspect it's `defects` afterwards it contains two defects:

```
[StartBoundaryNotFoundDefect(), MultipartInvariantViolationDefect()]
```

> `MultipartInvariantViolationDefect` – A message claimed to be a multipart, but no subparts were found. Note that when a message has this defect, its is_multipart() method may return false even though its content type claims to be multipart.

A consequence of the `StartBoundaryNotFoundDefect` is that the parser terminates parsing and sets the message payload to the body that has been captured so far - in this case, nothing, so the payload is an empty string, causing the exception that you are seeing when you run your code.

Arguably the fact that Python doesn't check whether payload is a `list` before calling `copy()` on it is a bug.

In practice, you have to handle these messages either by wrapping the iteration of attachments in a `try/except`, conditioning iteration on the contents of `msg.defects`, or parsing with `policy.strict` and discarding all messages that report defects.